# How to delete specific record from Google Datastore (in Java)?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, jdoql

I have some records in datastore, I want to delete a specific record from the table. for example in SQL , we use `delete * from table1 where name ="mike"` what is the equivalent code in java (I m using Eclipse with Google appengine API plugin)? or any other method to do that?

Comment: is name the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

//get all the matching objects
//loop over the matching objects
////deleting each object